# How to reload all cog functions

Tags: python, list, discord, discord.py

I want to reload all files with cogs in one command. I have a command with the function, to reload a file, but the command needs a filename. Is there a option to reload all files by default.
I'm thinking about this option:

```
import fnmatch
import os

pattern = "*.py
path = "cogs"

list = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir("./extensions"), pattern)
```

This outputs a list: `['event.py', 'info.py', 'start.py']`

Now how can I get this list and reload this scripts with this function?

```
@client.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
    client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about for loops?

```py
@client.command()
async def reload_all(ctx):
    for ext in extensions_list: # Idk how you called it
        client.reload_extension(f"cogs.{ext[:3]}")
```

Also there's already a `reload_extension` method, there's no need to unload/load the extension

Comment: Thans I found already a option with unloading all scripts and loading all scripts new